# Directive scope is not refreshing when provided value will be assign to directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created my own directive in angularjs and I noticed that directive scope is not refreshing when I change scope in main controller.

I made simple example which after 3s changing scope value, but the value is not changed in the directive. The issue exists only if I assign directive provided value to the directive scope.

Entire example is available here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3155/)

My directive:

```
myApp.directive('textPresenter', function() {
  return {               
    transclude : false,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      adfName : '='            
    },
    template: '{{xxx}}' ,
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.xxx = $scope.adfName; //this is the issue
    }
  };
});
```

$scope.xxx should refresh, after scope change in main controller.

Comment: Can't you simplify and write like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3156/)?

Comment: I can't. I made sample based on existing angularjs framework where I found this bug.

Comment: Why should `xxx` be updated? You assign a **value** to it once. That's it.

Comment: Yes I know but what code should I add to update it every time when adfName has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope value `adfName` in the template *is* bound to the one in your main controller by Angular, and will change when that one changes. If you change the template to:

```
template: '{{adfName}}'
```

as in http://jsfiddle.net/6bp7c/1/ , then you can see this.

However, from your comment, you say you can't do this. Then one possibility would be setup a watcher in your directive, to watch `adfName`, and set `xxx` to be equal to it when it changes:

```
$scope.$watch('adfName', function(newAdfName) {
  $scope.xxx = newAdfName;      
});
```

as can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/7V9FV/ . This is necessary because

```
$scope.xxx = $scope.adfName
```

just copies the contents of `adfName` and put it into `xxx`. If `adfName` later changes, then the contents of `xxx` are unaffected.

I am curious as to why you have to copy the variable though, and not just change the template to use the one passed into the directive.

Comment: Thanks $watch is working corretly. As I said in the comment I use ready framework (angular-dashboard-framework) and the author made that code. I can change the template but I asked out of curiosity